# Spaces in regex with multi line

Tags: regex, python-2.7

How do I change my regex to include multiple spaces with new lines, but not pick up blank lines. I'm not sure how to write the first group.

The format is any text (starting with a capital letter or number) followed a space and comma.

However I run into problems with space if there is more than one words as `\s+` picks up the new lines between the lines of text and I don't want to grab that.

```
# regex:
^([1-9A-Za-z]+\,\s)?(\d+\.\s)?
```

Bananas, 2017.

3D Bananas, 2018.

Some Bananas, 2020.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UfZXTc/1)

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve? What is the expect result for the given test case?

Comment: You allow lower-case letters in your regex. This finds any text starting with a capital letter or number, until it hits a comma and a space `([A-Z0-9].*),\s`

Comment: Try [`(?m)^(?!$)([1-9A-Za-z]+,\s)?(\d+\.\s)?`](https://regex101.com/r/UfZXTc/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
^([0-9A-Za-z]+(?:\s[0-9a-zA-Z]+)??\,\s)?(\d+\.\s)?
```

Where it matches any alphanumeric character(s) followed by an optional space and character(s), along with the other parameters.

`([0-9A-Za-z]+)` matches one or more alphanumeric characters,
`(?:\s[0-9a-zA-Z]+)??` is a non-capturing group which matches a space and some alphanumeric characters (if present),

and  the rest is your submitted code!